# Secured WCF service timing out on 2nd invocation of client channel

Tags: asp.net, wcf, wcf-security

We have a secured & authenticated WCF service which cannot use service references. Thus, we provide the interface for the contracts and open client channel manually.

We have found out that as long we open it once, everything works fine. We can call several methods several times. However, if the channel is closed or just set to a new instance, the Login() (which happens to be required for first step prior to using the service), times out.

To make the matters even more mysterious, this only happens on our production server. If I run the same project locally, I am able to login many times as I want. Consuming the methods inside a web browser (even on a code-behind ASPX page) do not have this problem even with the production server. ONLY when it's a .NET client trying to open a client channel against the production server, do we have this problem.

We are not even sure where to start looking. Any advices would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

As per @Rene's suggestion, we turned on logging on both sides. From client's log, there is a record of error which is basically the same timeout error we already got via the exception. Nothing meaningful. On the server's logs, there are records of service methods being invoked successfully even after 2nd login() and from server's POV, the request is served.

Additionally, I discovered that I could not even reproduce this issue on my machine using same test project to reproduce this problem. This reproduces on my developer's machine. I verified that we were at same version of .NET framework and Visual Studio. It has to be surely a client-side problem. What could be it?

Comment: enable wcf logging on both sides (client and server) and then analyze that.

Comment: When you say *times out* can you post actual error the client gets pls?

Comment: @Rene - working on it now.

Comment: @Tom - we just hang until the web service times out, and we get a timeout exception, that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else is looking for answer, we finally found it -- the issue is due to the need to set on client's side `System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` to some higher value. The default value is 2 but in reality this allows only one proxy to be created and be usable. Setting it to 3 would allow 2 proxies to be created & be used.